# Is there a way to make an Android WebView behave exactly like Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I have a button in a form on a web page that works always in Chrome but doesn't work sometimes on certain Android devices in the WebView.

Can I tell the Android WebView to behave exactly like the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Custom Chrome Tabs is being used on apps from sometime, and as you're looking can mock the Chrome experience.

More info here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/

Implementation Guide: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/

Github Demo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/custom-tabs-example-app

It is easy to replace WebView and integration is smooth.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like this leaves your app and brings you to the browser. Am I doing something incorrectly? I followed the implementation guide and every time it's triggering the url to open after leaving my app.

Comment: So it seems if you run this in an emulator that doesn't have Chrome installed, that's when it opens a separate browser.

Comment: @Masnaaaaaa -  This doesn't open browser. Do you see Chrome or any browser name in the recent apps when the link is opened? It is a new Chrome way of handling webpage. Many have been using this. And another good thing is, this can be themed according to your app.

Comment: Using Custom Chrome Tabs is generally recommended, but the OP might want to use a WebView so this doesn't really answer the question.